# ADB not working from TWRP for Galaxy S20

Tags: adb, twrp

Device: Galaxy S20 (x1s)
TWRP: 3.7.0 (latest)
ADB OS: Linux

ADB server doesn't detect the device when connected via USB with device in TWRP recovery. ADB server works fine when the phone is booted in normal mode or if I use another device in TWRP recovery. How to troubleshoot adbd on the device?

The TWRP for this device seems weird because it also mounts system, vendor, product partitions as read-only in recovery.fstab.

Comment: In most recovery ROMs adb isn't active by default (common recovery ROMS even have adb sideload capability which often has to be activated manually). I don't know how much the TWRP ROMs for different devices differ,, thus if what you observe is a bug or simply the default behavior.